# How to use correctly Panel in block/editor?

Tags: block-editor

I am using Panel from `@wordpress/component` and my problem is that, every time I click on PanelBody, it disappear and I cannot do anything.

```
<Panel header="My Panel">
{acc.map((x)=>(
    <PanelBody
        title="My Block Settings"
        icon={ more }
        initialOpen={ true }
        onToggle={ () => toggleState(index) }
    >
        <PanelRow>My Panel Inputs and Labels</PanelRow>
    </PanelBody>))}
</Panel>
```

```
 function toggleState(event, ind) {
      return (
        setAttributes(( previousState ) => ( {
       ...AccordationDate[ind].toggle = ! previousState[ind].toggle }))
      }
```

Comment: A `PanelBody` should contain individual inputs, and those inputs should have triggers. For example, a `TextControl` would have a trigger that on update, it sets a text attribute. The `PanelBody` itself should not have any defined `onToggle` event.

Comment: you're also not providing `key` attributes to React so it can muddle up the elements if you're not careful